# Json loader multiple geometries - syntax

Tags: json, syntax, import, three.js

I am trying to import multiple geometries, e.g. two different and separated cubes, with just one .json file.

The model is NOT coming from Blender. In my code I have just used a simple JSONLoader, no materials.
I could not find the correct syntax.
This is an example geometry, loaded just fine:

```
"vertices": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 25.25, 0.0,46.0, 25.25, 0.0,46.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 25.25, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 25.25,0.0, 25.25, 25.25,0.0, 0.0, 0.0,46.0, 0.0, 0.0,46.0, 0.0, 25.25,0.0, 0.0, 25.25,46.0, 0.0, 0.0,46.0, 25.25, 0.0,46.0, 25.25, 25.25,46.0, 0.0, 25.25,46.0, 25.25, 0.0,0.0, 25.25, 0.0,0.0, 25.25, 25.25,46.0, 25.25, 25.25,0.0, 0.0, 25.25,46.0, 0.0, 25.25,46.0, 25.25, 25.25,0.0, 25.25, 25.25],

"uvs": [[0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]],

"faces": [0,0,1,2,0,4,5,6,0,8,9,10,0,12,13,14,0,16,17,18,0,20,21,22,0,0,2,3,0,4,6,7,0,8,10,11,0,12,14,15,0,16,18,19,0,20,22,23]
```

let's say I want to add another separate geometry under this one in the same JSON, perhaps with different names.
What's the correct syntax?
I already checked:

- Mr. doob JSON model format 3 and JSON geometry format 4 syntax, no reference to multiple geometries
- The syntax of an example model exported from Blender. This uses a "geometries" property to store vertices and faces. Still doesn't work for me.
- The examples that come with Three.js always import a single geometry.

Comment: After looking at another example:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tparisi/3dsMaxWebGL/master/exports/3rdPerson/scene.js
I realized that I'll probably need the SceneLoader to handle this kind of import. I'll make some tests now.

Comment: After hours spent unraveling the "simplest" example of the SceneLoader that comes with Three.js (webgl_loader_scene), I managed to import multiple geometries. You can "group" geometries and import more than one at a time, since you are in fact importing a scene. 
Unfortunately, this is true only with the example given -- I can't get it to work when I try to use a SceneLoader in my own code. It's very difficult to find a source to understand how it works/how I should use it, and it seems that the only thing one can do is extricate the uselessly complicated examples, which is a pain,

Comment: If anyone knows a way of doing the same with the simple JSON loader, please help!